# Regex change "array()" to "[]" in Sublime 3

Tags: php, regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Yet another RegEx question.
I have many PHP files to change from array('foo', 'bar') to new style ['foo', 'bar']

So far I came up with this:

```
array\(([^\(]*?)\)
```

But it doesn't pick up multi-line definitions. I've tried something like this, but it's even worse, since it picks up wrong closing brackets:

```
(?s)array\(([^\(].*?)\)
```

For example, some data that needs to get replaced:

```
$foobar = $this->foobar('foo_bar', array(
    'foo'   =>  array('foobar' => array('barfoo')),
    'bar' => array(
        'bar' => 'foobar',
        'foo' => 'barfoo',
)));
```

So the above example would look like this:

```
$foobar = $this->foobar('foo_bar', [
    'foo' => ['foobar' => ['barfoo']],
    'bar' => [ 
        'bar' => 'foobar',
        'foo' => 'barfoo',
 ]]);
```

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Do you mean this? [`(?:array\()(.*)?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/tP3aN5/1)

Comment: Matei Mihai, don't ask me please =) it's not my call, we're updating an old project to new framework, so we're changing array definitions along with 
it.

Comment: Shafizadeh, nope, still doesn't pick up multilines =(

Comment: @lime The example you give has no `array()`s with `,`, only `=>`. Did you want to change `array('foo' => 'bar')` to `['foo', 'bar']` too?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Druzion nono! the structure must stay the same. So the above example would look like this:

`$foobar = $this->foobar('foo_bar', [
    'foo'   =>  ['foobar' => ['barfoo']],
    'bar' => [
        'bar' => 'foobar',
        'foo' => 'barfoo',
]]);`

Comment: I could only [write that](https://ideone.com/d07D2J) in PHP. I am not sure you can port it to a one-regex solution for SublimeText.

Comment: Or you can use multiple passes with `array(\(((?>[^()]++|(?1))*)\))` and replace with `[$2]` in Sublime Text

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh yeah! Thanks a lot! Multiple passes is absolutely fine. This works exactly as I needed. Submit it as an answer, I'll mark it as a correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sublime Text, you can use multiple passes with

```
\barray(\(((?>[^()]++|(?1))*)\))
```

and replace with `[$2]`.

The pattern matches:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `array` - a literal character sequence `array`
- `(\(((?>[^()]++|(?1))*)\))` - Group 1 matching nested, paired parentheses and *capturing* the contents between paired parentheses into Group 2 (that is why you need to backreference Group 2 with `$2` in the replacement).

Comment: I will add demo and screenshot when I am at my desktop. Glad to help.

Comment: I am still short of time, but I will add what I promised.

Comment: Works fine, but don't forget to repeat until all nested `array()` calls are replaced.

Answer (score 5):

As far I know python regex does not support nesting of brackets and regex are in general not recommended for that tasks.
If you don't want to write a program, but do it in ST I would recommend and other approach. The [Surround](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Surround) package does a good job in changing the surrounding brackets. You can install it an then:

1. select all array starts
2. delete the array keyword
3. move inside the parens
4. change the surrounding parens to braces. To do this press `ctrl+shift+p` and write `Surround: change surround`. Insert `)` in the first input field and `]` in the second input field. (If you insert `[` it will add an addition space inside.)

demonstration:

[image: toggle_php_array_demo]

Comment: S&R is using Boost regex flavor, not Python. It supports recursion.

Comment: This is really nice! I might use it as well. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

That regex shouldn't have problems matching across line boundaries, but it is incorrect. `[^\(].*?` insures the the first character after the opening parenthesis isn't another open paren, but after that, anything goes.  You want to make sure all the characters are not parentheses (open or close).  This is all you need:

```
array\(([^()]*)\)
```

Replace with `[$1]`.  Of course, you'll have to make multiple passes until there are no more matches.

I'm assuming there will never be any parentheses that are not part of a `array(...)` structure;  it there are, the job gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: This didn't work. And yes, there are plenty parentheses not part of array(...) inside and outside the definitions.

Comment: Okay, then we'll need a more complete example.